# Change the appearance of labels and input fields (from a Model Form) used in a DJango template

Tags: django, templates

I am using a script below (that resides in a DJango template) to display `input fields` that are associated with a particular `Model Form`. The purpose of this template is to add and modify data for a Model.

The name of the template is : model_name_form.html (ex: customer_form.html for the Model representation of the table Customer)

In order to add/modify data, the `Model Form` is being used.

The problem is that when using the script below, a type of default presentation is being used for the fields. In my case, the fields need to be more customized.

The customized `labels` and `input fields` make the form look much nicer.

**I start out with this (which is in the template that displays the form):**

```
   {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <span class="text-danger small"> {{ field.errors }} </span>
            </div>
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2"> {{ field.label_tag }} </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10"> {{ field }} </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

**Which turns into this:**

```
<div class="form-group">

   <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">

     <span class="text-danger small">  
     </span>

   </div>

   <label class="control-label col-sm-2"> 
      <label for="id_companyname">Company Name:</label> 

   </label>
   <div class="col-sm-10"> 

      <input name="companyname" id="id_companyname" type="text" maxlength="30"> 

   </div>

</div>
```

**But what is needed is a label/input presentation similar to the following:**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Default Input Group</label>
           <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" type="text">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">@</span>
           </div>
</div>
```

**How can one control the attributes associated with :**

```
{{ field.errors }}
{{ field.label_tag }}
{{ field }}  <<< especially this one
```

**For example, one can see above,  `{{ field }}` produces**

```
<input name="companyname" id="id_companyname" type="text" maxlength="30">
```

**But what is needed is:**

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" type="text">
```

**How can one control the way labels and input fields are presented?**

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can use widget attributes to have more control over the HTML output, for example:

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):

     class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'my_field': TextInput(attrs = {
                'placeholder': 'Ingrese el contacto',
                'class': 'form-control',
                'data-validation': 'custom',

            }),
            'my_other_field': Select(attrs = {
                'class': 'form-control selectpicker',
                'data-live-search': 'true',
                'title': 'Elegir un tipo',
                'data-validation': 'required',
                'data-validation-error-msg': 'Debe elegir una de las opciones.',
            }),
```

In your case you could do:

```
        widgets = {
            'my_field': TextInput(attrs = {
                'placeholder': 'Username',
                'class': 'form-control',
                'aria-describedby': 'sizing-addon1',

            }),
```

For more control, you can use [custom template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/), or even try the library [django crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but it adds a layer of complexity that maybe is not needed.

Comment: thanks for the response! Out of curiosity, is there a way to set characteristics/attributes of a field by perhaps input type (ex: all <input type="text...>") - OR - is there a way to just set a default for all of the fields that are to be displayed for the Model (ex: all fields getting a class="form-control") TIA

Comment: I guess youd could find a way, but I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: OK - thanks again for the input.I will try what you have mentioned and update the message with my findings. Wish me luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the default form label was missing spaces. I was able to fix the issue by overwriting the default label in `forms.py` to be blank:

```
quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(label='', choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES)
```

and then creating a new label in the HTML. It didn't work to just overwrite the label in `forms.py`.